# Is it better to create a queue in a freeRTOS application using freeRTOS queue API, or by using a custom data structure?

Tags: c, queue, freertos

I have written an application using C under Linux where queues are created using custom structures. The code is running just fine. Now I would like to adapt that code to run it using freeRTOS. It is my first time dealing with a rtos. While going through the documentation, I found that freeRTOS supports queues API. So, I was wondering if I have to use those API to create queues, or can I just keep the custom structs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Queues are included in freeRTOS because they are required for task switching and other core OS features to work. If you are getting low on storage space (flash memory), it may make sense to use the "free" (as in, it's going to already be there) implementation in freeRTOS. In addition, freeRTOS's queue implementation is pretty good overall.

If you are in somewhat of a timecrunch and you have plenty of flash, I'd just keep with what works. If you've tested it and it works, keep using it.